# Can I fix intellij output that prints a trailing unicode?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Here is my Intellij version:

[image]

The code is simple. `System.out.print("V\u0305")`

This is how the output should be:

[image]

This is the output for Intellij:

[image]

Any idea why this is or how to fix it?

Comment: please enter texts instead of images

Comment: I don't see the harm in having 3 images with enough text to cover what those images mean.

Comment: Got the answer from here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203479304-Intellij-outputs-font-unicode-as-trailing-chars?page=1#community_comment_203904044

Comment: The only "harm" you are doing is to yourself, given that opening content from image hosting sites are disabled in several company networks, thus you voluntarily reduce the number of people who might deal with your question at all. Glad to hear you managed to resolve the issue though.

Comment: @hammerfest I understand OP's usage of images, as the custom character may not properly be reflected on each machine's locale. In this case, using an image is likely to be more appropriate. However, the IntelliJ version should be in text format.

Comment: @Jerrybibo: I see your point, though I still suppose descriptions "V with line on top"/ "Roman 5000" or "V and line forming about square root symbol" in addition would have suited those perfectly who can not open the images (not speaking of Idea version of course)